# A property of subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Is true that if $\{ x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ and :

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} x_{n_k} = L $$

then :

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} x_{n_k+1} = L $$

Answer (score 2):

No, if $x_n=(-1)^n$, $$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{2n} = 1,$$ but 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{1+2n} = -1.$$

For the question in the comment section: Does x_{n_k+1} converge? Clearly no, for example $x_n=\cos(\pi n)$, then
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{2n} = \lim_{k\to \infty} \cos(2\pi n) =1,$$ but 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{2n+1} = \lim_{k\to \infty} \cos(\pi(2n+1)) \text{ Doesn't exist, because the sequence alternates between } 1 \text{ and }-1.$$

Comment: Thanks!! , a little different question : is true that $\{ x_{n_k+1} \}$ converge?

Comment: Also, not necesarilly

Comment: @Orested No. Instead of defining $x_{2n + 1} = -1$, try defining $x_{2n + 1} = n$. Basically, knowing the terms of $x_{2n}$ tells you nothing at all about the $x_{2n + 1}$ terms.

Comment: @TheoBendit I was about to edit the answer, but you pointed it out first

Comment: @miraunpajaro Don't let me stop you editing. It's a good thing to include.